# Is there a standard term for the following flaw in the data?

Tags: classification, terminology, datasets, data-labelling, training-datasets

I wonder if following characteristic of data has some standard "professional" or scientific term associated with it.

Let's assume that I have a set of dog/cat images labeled 0 for a cat and 1 for a dog. My purpose is to extract (classify) as many true dog images as possible, with the smallest amount of non-dog images. But the problem with data is that:

- some dogs images are labeled as 0
- some cats images are labeled as 1
- some images are of other animals or non-animal objects and can have both labels 1 and 0

Is there any specific term describing such cases, or they are  just "noisy" data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is referred to as ***label noise*** (or *noisy labels*), and it is indeed different from just "noisy data"; quoting from the 2014 paper [Classiﬁcation in the Presence of Label Noise: a Survey](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261601383_Classification_in_the_Presence_of_Label_Noise_A_Survey):

> In this survey,
> it is assumed that each training sample is associated with an
> observed label. This label often corresponds to the true class of
> the sample, but it may be *subjected to a noise process before
> being presented to the learning algorithm*. It is therefore
> important to distinguish the true class of an instance from its
> observed label. The process which pollutes labels is called
> label noise and must be separated from feature (or attribute)
> noise which affects the value of features.

You may also find the (preprint) paper [Label Noise Types and Their Effects on Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.10471) useful; there, the authors propose a taxonomy of different types of label noise:

> Label noise types can be subdivided into
> three main groups as follows.
>
> • **Uniform noise**: Flipping probability of label from its
> true class to any other class is equally distributed. Many
> works in literature use synthetic uniform label noise by
> just flipping labels randomly for a given percentage of
> data instances [21]–[24].
>
> • **Class-dependent noise**: Flipping probability of label
> depends on the true class of the data instance. This
> is mostly represented by a confusion matrix and can
> be designed in different ways. The easiest way is to
> attain inter-class transition probabilities just random [25],
> so that there is still class dependence since transition
> probabilities are given according to classes but without
> any correlation to class similarities. In a more structured
> way, noise transition matrix can be designed in a way that
> similar classes have a bigger probability to be flipped to
> each other [26]–[30]. Some works use pairwise noise,
> in which transition from one class can only be defined
> to one another class [31]–[35]. Work of [36] checks the
> popularity of classes and constructs transition matrix so
> that mislabeling happens from popular class to unpopular
> class or vice versa.
>
> • **Feature-dependent noise**: The probability of mislabeling
> depends on features of instances. In order to generate
> feature-dependent noise, features of each instance should
> be extracted, and their similarities to other instances from
> different classes should be evaluated. Unlike uniform and
> class-dependent noise, there are much fewer implemen-
> tations of synthetic feature-dependent label noise. One
> particular work in this field is [37], where data is clustered
> with the kNN algorithm, and labels are flipped randomly
> for clusters of data. This method provides concentrated
> noise in the feature space. But, this type of synthetic noise
> doesn’t evaluate the instance similarities and therefore
> different from our proposed approach. Alternatively, in
> case there is a surrounding text for each image in the
> dataset, some works create noisy labels from the interpretations of these texts [38]–[41], assuming surrounding
> texts are related to features of data. But this approach is
> restricted to datasets with surrounding user-defined texts,
> which is not the case for most of the time.

Other possibly useful resources on the subject:

- [A Comprehensive Introduction to Label Noise](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Eaxk/ESANNtut.pdf) (conference paper, 2014)
- [A Little Talk on Label Noise](http://knowdive.disi.unitn.it/2018/09/a-little-talk-on-label-noise/) (blog post, 2018)
- [Data Noise and Label Noise in Machine Learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-noise-and-label-noise-in-machine-learning-98c8a3c8322e) (blog post, 2021)